# Calculation of Shannon entropy given the mutual information of Binary strings

Tags: boolean-algebra, information-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ two different binary strings of length $l$. Suppose the Mutual Information (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) of $A$ and $B$ is known to be $I$.

Now suppose bit-wise a Boolean function is applied to get another bit-string $C$. The Boolean function is $f(0,0)=0, f(0,1)=0, f(1,0)=0, f(1,1)=1$.

Under this function f, what would be the Shannon entropy of the bit-string $C$? I want to know the least upper bound and greatest lower bound of the Shannon entropy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you previously tried? Why haven't they worked?

Comment: You have defined A and B twice. "Suppose A and B are two binary strings..." and "Suppose the mutual information of two discrete r.v.s A and B...".

Comment: My strong guess is the entropy of the bit-string C would be less than 0.5. Am I right? I am interested more on least upper bound and greatest lower bound.

Comment: @James, Question is edited.

Comment: Say the last $l$ bits of $A$ and the last $l$ bits of $B$ are all mutually independent and uniform in $\{0,1\}$. Moreover, let $(A_1, B_1)$ also be independent from everything else, and have some joint distribution that ensures the 1/2 mutual information. Then wouldn't the entropy of $C$ be linear in $l$?

Comment: First, is the mutual information 1/2 or $\ell/2$? (If you're copying this question from somewhere, note that 1/2 and $l/2$ can look very similar.) Second, I think your guess is wrong; try some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutual information tells you nothing about the entropy of *C*.

The mutual information can be $l$ and the entropy of $C$ can be $0$: set
$$ A(i) = 1-B(i) = \begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ with probability } 1/2, \\ 1 \mbox{ with probability } 1/2. \end{cases}$$

The mutual information can be $l$ and the entropy of $C$ can be $l$: set
$$A(i) = B(i) = \begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ with probability } 1/2, \\ 1 \mbox{ with probability } 1/2. \end{cases} $$

The mutual information can be $0$ and the entropy of $C$ can be $l$: set
$$ A(i) = \begin{cases} 0 \mbox{ with probability } 1 - 1/\sqrt{2},\\
1 \mbox{ with probability } 1/\sqrt{2}, \end{cases}$$
and use the same distribution for $B(i)$, making $A$ independent of $B$.

Finally, the mutual information can be $0$ and the entropy of $C$ can be $0$:
set
$$A(i) = B(i) = 1.$$

And you can get any convex combination of these cases by using these same distributions on substrings of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest lower bound is 0 bits:

$A=1-B$, so $I(A,B)=H(A)=H(B)=0.5$. But with your definition of $f$, $C=0$, and hence $H(C)=0$

An upper bound is given in the comments by Peter Shor.

Comment: How come $C=A=B?$

Comment: Because $A=B$ by assumption.  If $A_i=0$ and $B_i=0$, then $C_i=f(A_i,B_i)$. But $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(1,1)=1$.

Comment: A and B are two independent binary strings. They are not same.

Comment: If they are independent then the mutual information will be zero. The bounds I stated hold -- of course -- only for the question you asked above. If you have additional constraints not mentioned in your question (e.g., $A$ and $B$ are not equal), then the bounds may be different.

Comment: Yes. But mutual information is 0.5. This says that A and B are not equal bit strings, right?

Comment: No, this does not say that. If the entropy of string $A$ is 0.5, and if $B=A$, then the mutual information between $A$ and $B$ is also 0.5.

Comment: I got it now. Would you please tell me for two different bit strings A and B for which mutual information is known. Then what would be the maximum and minimum entropy of the bit string C with the rule $f$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24867/discussion-between-bernhard-geiger-and-fukuzita).

Comment: -1: The mutual information can be 0 and the entropy of C can be $H(1/4)\cdot l$ if you let A and B be independent strings where each bit is 0 or 1 with probability $1/2$. And by altering this example slightly, you can make the mutual information $1/2$ and not change $H(C )$ much. This upper bound is wrong.

Comment: You are right, my upper bound is wrong! Thanks for the clarification. I will edit my post and point to your comment.